# Xamarin: Can not resolve reference: `System.Web`, referenced by [referenced project]

Tags: android, xamarin, system.web

I'm using Xamarin with VS2019. The contained android project has recently started to give the following build errors.  platform is android 8.1.  I recently upgraded from VS2017.  However everything was building ok until very recently.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Suppression State  Error    Can not resolve reference: `System.Web`, referenced by `MobileApp.Shared` > `SSW.Api.PublicInterface` > `SSW.Api.Common` > `EntityFramework` > `SSW.Cache` > `Castle.Windsor` > `Castle.Core`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `System.Web`, or remove the reference to `MobileApp.Shared`.    MobileApp.Android.SSW

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Suppression State Error     Can not resolve reference: `System.Runtime.Caching`, referenced by `MobileApp.Shared` > `SSW.Api.PublicInterface` > `SSW.Api.Common` > `EntityFramework` > `SSW.Cache` > `Castle.Windsor` > `Castle.Core`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `System.Runtime.Caching`, or remove the reference to `MobileApp.Shared`.    MobileApp.Android.CAM

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Suppression State Error Can not resolve reference: `System.Configuration`, referenced by `MobileApp.Shared` > `SSW.Api.PublicInterface` > `SSW.Api.Common` > `EntityFramework` > `SSW.Cache` > `Castle.Windsor` > `Castle.Core`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `System.Configuration`, or remove the reference to `MobileApp.Shared`.    MobileApp.Android.CAM

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Suppression State Error     "obj\Debug\81\MobileApp.Android.dll;obj\Debug\81\MobileApp.Android.dll" is an invalid value for the "OutputAssembly" parameter of the "Csc" task. Multiple items cannot be passed into a parameter of type "Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem".   MobileApp.Android

Answer (score 1):

I found System.Web at "NETFramework" Library:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1

I've added the reference to xamarin.android project an it now builds

Comment: Could you please mark your reply as an answer so that others who have similar questions will get help from here?